# How to call method which returns type byte32?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I am trying to call a method symbol, of contract DAI

```
contract.methods.symbol().call()
```

This contract returns a value not of type `string`, but of type `byte32`

And due to this fact I always get an error:

> Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

How can I do it properly?

Comment: What does your `symbol` method do? If I understand it correct it is a method you add when creating the contract.

Comment: symbol return token Symbol

For standard is string. 
Example:

string  public  symbol;

But sometimes it's

bytes32  public  symbol;

Comment: Does the error occur when you call `contract.methods.symbol().call()` or later when you try to use whatever is returned from that method?

Comment: this occur only for DAI, cause DAI return bytes32, for other tokens in my list code work good.

Comment: Find solution, need change output in ABI from string to bytes 32

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned over at the [ethereum stackexchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23058/how-to-convert-string-to-bytes32-in-web3js) web3 has util functions to convert between `string` and `byte32`:

```
const val32 = contract.methods.symbol().call();
const valString = web3.toAscii(val32);
```

if you're on a web3 version 0.x.

Or:

```
const val32 = contract.methods.symbol().call();
const valString = web3.utils.toAscii(val32);
```

for a web3 version 1.0.

Comment: Yes I now, but this will not work if You not change output in ABI from string to bytes 32 

I did try catch, if return standard string, use standard ABI, if return no string use ABI with output bytes 32 instead string.